# Override Antd's selected Item color

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I want to override the `background-color` property of the `ant-menu-item-selected` class. By default it appears blue.

```
import { Menu } from 'antd';
const { Item } = Menu;

//item2 will be rendered with the class 'ant-menu-item-selected'
const MyComp = () => (
  <Menu theme="dark" defaultSelectedKeys={["item2"]} mode="horizontal">
    <Item key="item1">Item 1</Item>
    <Item key="item2">Item 2</Item>
  </Menu>
);

ReactDOM.render(<MyComp />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

How should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to override `Ant Design`'s properties with a higher priority. First, I defined a CSS class on each of my `Item` elements:

```
<Item key="item1" className="customclass">Item 1</Item>
```

Then I added the CSS:

```
.ant-menu.ant-menu-dark .ant-menu-item-selected.customclass {
  background-color: green; /*Overriden property*/
}
```

The first part before `customclass` is there to get the same priority than the properties of Ant Design. The class `customclass` just adds the little bit of priority needed to surpass that of Ant Design.

Comment: this.  right here.  and if you want to disable selected menu item highlighting (which should be a feature built in....) you can just do this and set background-color: transparent

Answer (score 3):

```
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-item:hover,
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu:hover,
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-item-active,
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-active,
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-item-open,
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-open,
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-item-selected,
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu-selected {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

It's working for me!

Answer (score 2):

On the documentation of `And-Design` You have an option called : `style`

Inside you can put all you want like `style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}` for example. 
You can make an `hover` effect also inside a style attribute.

> How can use a `style` attribute if I don't know witch items are active ?

Very simple, with `React` you have a state management you could set a key like `isActive` when item is selected you apply style what you want and if it not true, you apply nothing.

And for knowing witch items are selected, you have a props with `Ant-D` his called `onSelect`

> Please check this link : [ANT DESIGN](https://ant.design/components/menu/)

Comment: But I cannot use this as I don't know in advance which Item will be selected (and on which Item I must put the style).

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, you can set a state at true when item is selected, and you `style` props you can check if the state are true or not and if it's true, you can set this style and if it false, you can set nothing.

Comment: But how would you achieve to know which element is selected without some hideous code that queries the list of items to know which one has the `ant-menu-item-selected` class?

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I solved my problem another way. I posted my answer below, feel free to point out my mistakes if I made some.

Comment: I used @emotion/react with Global and css and override li.ant-menu-item query. You can inspect query via developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

By doing so much research I found that we can use the @emotion/styled package to override Antd's selected Item color(::: You can add @emotion/styled using command **yarn add @emotion/styled** or **npm install @emotion/styled** )

const CustomMenu = styled(Menu)`

&& .ant-menu-item-selected {

background-color: #000000;

}
}
`

Comment: Perfect!! , thanks so much, why this is not upvoted i do not know. Far better than altering the stylesheet because it can be added dynamically

Answer (score 0):

**Overriden property**

```
:host ::ng-deep .ant-menu.ant-menu-light .ant-menu-item-selected {
  border-bottom-color: #4a235a;
}
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using `:global` we can override detail ant design styles

```
div { // any parent element
  :global {
    .ant-menu-item-selected {
      border-bottom-color: #4a235a;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding the style using a less file, you most likely want to set the correct primary alternatives to affect the selection background color:

```
@import "~antd/dist/antd.less";
@primary-color: #e42;
@primary-1: rgb(137, 41, 22);
@primary-2: rgb(118, 49, 35);
@primary-5: rgb(94, 51, 42);
@primary-6: #e42;
@primary-7: rgb(255, 120, 93);
```